# WTForms-JSON with optional nesting using FormField

Tags: wtforms, wtforms-json

I'm using [WTForms-JSON](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-json) and processing nested forms. I'd like to make an inner form optional, but if the inner form is present, I'd like its fields to be required. The problem I'm running into is that `FormField` doesn't accept validators.

*(Although I'm using WTForms-JSON, I believe this applies to vanilla WTForms as well.)*

**This code works but doesn't behave the way I want:**

```
class InnerForm(Form):
    foo_id = IntegerField("Foo ID", [Required()])

class OuterForm(Form):
    inner = FormField(InnerForm)
```

The problem with the above code is that `inner` is implicitly required. Oddly, while `validate()` returns `False` when `inner` is omitted, `errors` is empty.

**This code doesn't doesn't work:**

```
class InnerForm(Form):
    foo_id = IntegerField("Foo ID", [Required()])

class OuterForm(Form):
    inner = FormField(InnerForm, "Inner", [Optional()])
```

The latter produces this error:

```
TypeError: FormField does not accept any validators. Instead, define them on the enclosed form.
```

**My question is: how can I make `inner` optional, but require `foo_id` if `inner` is present?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap the `FormField` in a [`FieldList`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList), with `max_entries` set to 1.  `FieldList` also supports validators, but since `min_entries` is 0 by default you should not need any.  The only annoyance will be that you will have to unwrap the inner form's data if it is available.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion, but unfortunately it would change the API and require client-side changes or server-side preprocessing to munge the data structure, and neither of them are a good option for me. I might just patch WTForms to make `FormField()` honor `Required()` and `Optional()`.

Comment: @JimStewart - fair enough.  Definitely worth a pull request as well, since they are working on WTForms 2.0 right now :-)

Comment: I'm accepting this because there's no support for what I want and this is a good workaround. If I ever get around to patching WTForms I'll update here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @aryeh for `OptionalFormField`. I just put here my slightly improved (in my opinion) version:

```
class OptionalFormField(FormField):

    def process(self, formdata, *args, **kwargs):
        self._formdata = formdata
        return super(OptionalFormField, self).process(formdata, *args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._formdata:
            for field_name in self._formdata.keys():
                if field_name.startswith(self.name + self.separator):
                    return super(OptionalFormField, self).validate(*args, **kwargs)
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes here looking for a solution to this, here is a simple one:

```
from wtforms.fields import FormField, _unset_value

class OptionalFormField(FormField):

    def process(self, formdata, data=_unset_value):
        self._formdata = formdata
        return super(OptionalFormField, self).process(formdata, data=data)

    def validate(self, form, extra_validators=tuple()):
        if extra_validators:
            raise TypeError('FormField does not accept in-line validators, as it gets errors from the enclosed form.')

        # Run normal validation only if there is data for this form
        for field_name in self._formdata.keys():
            if field_name.find(self.name) == 0:
                return self.form.validate()

        return True
```

What this does is it only runs the form validation if it finds keys in the formdata that pertain to that form.